# swift iOS 7 replacement counter for time and distance

Tags: swift, core-data, core-location, healthkit

I have the following code in my running app

```
func eachSecond(timer: NSTimer) {

        if deviceversion.floatValue >= 8.0 {
        seconds++
        let secondsQuantity = HKQuantity(unit: HKUnit.secondUnit(), doubleValue: seconds)
        timeLabel.text = "Tijd: " + secondsQuantity.description
        let distanceQuantity = HKQuantity(unit: HKUnit.meterUnit(), doubleValue: distance)
        distanceLabel.text = "Afstand: " + distanceQuantity.description

        let paceUnit = HKUnit.secondUnit().unitDividedByUnit(HKUnit.meterUnit())
        let paceQuantity = HKQuantity(unit: paceUnit, doubleValue: seconds / distance)
        paceLabel.text = "Snelheid: " + paceQuantity.description
        }else{


        }
    }
```

This is using health kit which comes with ios 8. I also want people to use the app on their 7.1 iPhone. Is there an easy way to get the same information by using swift for iOS 7?

I can't seem to find how to do this and store this for later use. They made it real easy in iOS 8.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to deploy your app on iOS releases before 8.0, you should perform the calculations directly rather than relying on HealthKit to provide the conveniences.

Comment: i have just seems that only 8% of the devices run ios 7, so there is no need to target that market share.